# Android - can't get broadcastreceiver to work

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I try to launch a service at boot, but it never starts the service. I added `<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>` to the intent-filter of the receiver, but when I connect my android 8.0 phone to power, it also doesn't work.

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.madmagic.oqrpc">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" 
tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MainService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".StartAtBoot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**StartAtBoot:**

```
public class StartAtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //this never shows up when connecting to power

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainService.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
}
```

**MainService:**

```
public class MainService extends Service {

public static boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    isRunning = true;

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ConnectionChecker.run(this); //when device has wifi connection, this will run connected() method
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    isRunning = false;
}

public void connected() {
    //things to do when it has wifi connection
}
}
```

In my `MainActivity` class, I start this service using the same way as in my `StartAtBoot` class, and there it works fine when I open the application. So the service is working fine, its just that the `StartAtBoot` class doesn't run the code.

Comment: If you are on Oreo or above, you could be affected by these restrictions: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` is not a [listed exception](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) to the limits on implicit `Intent` broadcasts. Your app cannot register for it in the manifest.

If your goal is to do work periodically, but only if the device has power, use `JobScheduler` or `WorkManager`.

Comment: I totally forgot android 8 did those things. My main goal was to have it start at boot, but that doesnt work. Is it same for that or can you still register start at boot in the manifest?

Comment: `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is a listed exception, so that should work. It's also a scenario that some device manufacturers have messed with, so you may have other problems.